# IDA Pro Renaming Imports

Tags: ida, ida-plugin, x86-64, idapro-sdk, iat

This PE file destroys its import address table. However, all the function addresses are in this `_rdata` segment here:

[image: rdata_segment]

Any straight forward way to rename these functions?

Answer (score 3):

Before you dump the process's memory to disk, use a tool like [Scylla](http://www.woodmann.com/collaborative/tools/index.php/Scylla) to reconstruct the Import Table.

[image: Scylla]

Answer (score 2):

While in debugger, select the import table and run `idc\renimp.idc`.

Top comment from the file:

```
/*
   Rename imports.

   This script renames entries of a dynamically built import table.
   For example, from a table like this:

      dd offset ntdll_NtPowerInformation
      dd offset ntdll_NtInitiatePowerAction
      dd offset ntdll_NtSetThreadExecutionState
      dd offset ntdll_NtRequestWakeupLatency
      dd offset ntdll_NtGetDevicePowerState
      dd offset ntdll_NtIsSystemResumeAutomatic
      dd offset ntdll_NtRequestDeviceWakeup
      dd offset ntdll_NtCancelDeviceWakeupRequest
      dd offset ntdll_RtlQueryRegistryValues


   it will create a table like this:

      NtPowerInformation dd offset ntdll_NtPowerInformation
      NtInitiatePowerAction dd offset ntdll_NtInitiatePowerAction
      NtSetThreadExecutionState dd offset ntdll_NtSetThreadExecutionState
      NtRequestWakeupLatency dd offset ntdll_NtRequestWakeupLatency
      NtGetDevicePowerState dd offset ntdll_NtGetDevicePowerState
      NtIsSystemResumeAutomatic dd offset ntdll_NtIsSystemResumeAutomatic
      NtRequestDeviceWakeup dd offset ntdll_NtRequestDeviceWakeup
      NtCancelDeviceWakeupRequest dd offset ntdll_NtCancelDeviceWakeupRequest
      RtlQueryRegistryValues dd offset ntdll_RtlQueryRegistryValues

   Usage: select the import table and run the script.

   Known problems: if the dll name contains an underscore, the function
   names might be incorrect. Special care is taken for the ws2_32.dll but
   other dlls will have wrong function names.

*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely using a process dump.  those addresses would depend on the Windows version and service pack.  If you had a chance to run it in a VM, try volatility.  do a procdump then impscan.  impscan can give you an idc that renames those addresses to their respective API names.

this method works well even with non-PE injected codes.

https://github.com/volatilityfoundation/volatility/wiki/Command%20Reference%20Mal#impscan